# Set several classnames in Clojurescript

Tags: dom, clojurescript

This is very basic, but i can't figure out :)

I can set a nameclass with:

`(set! (.-className element) nameclass)`

But I would like add more than one classname
something like:

`(set! (.-className element) nameclass "myclass")`

How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would that work?

```
(set! (.-className element) (str/join " " [nameclass "myclass"])) ; str = clojure.string
```